# Convert from Local Client System's Time to CST and vice versa

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, timezone

I need to store the datetime in CST timezone regardless of any timezone given.

The Clients who access the application are from from various time zones, like IST, CST, EST,...

I need to store all the datetime entered by the client in CST timezone to my database. And while retrieving, i need to convert back to there local timezone.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally accepted to store all datetime values in your DB in the GMT/UTC format.

For those who want to render the UTC value to a particular time zone for different users of the application, like wilpeck mentioned, it's suggested that you determine the end users locale and:

- when persisting, store the locale with the UTC date value
- when reading, render the UTC value to local time with the associated locale value

**EDIT:**

For example:

You might have a table with a field **StartDateTime** so to support multiple time zones you might have an additional field **StartDateTimeOffset**. If the client is in the Indian Standard Time (IST) zone you might have a datetime value of 2009/10/13 14:45 which is 2009/10/13 09:15 in UTC. So you would store the UTC value (2009/10/13 09:15) in the field **StartDateTime** and store the offset +05:30 in the **StartDateTimeOffset** field. Now when you read this value back from the DB you can use the offset to convert the UTC datetime value (2009/10/13 09:15) back to the local time of 2009/10/13 14:45.

Comment: Can i have a sample for that? for ex.: Client's system is at IST and server is at CST.

Comment: Thanks cottsak, it's very useful

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would most likely work out for you.  I may be have an incorrect value for the time zone id but I think this is close.  The timezone stuff is available in .NET 3.5+

```
DateTime clientDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime centralDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(clientDateTime, "Central Time (US & Canada)");
```

EDIT:

If you can store DateTime in UTC by detecting the client timezone whenever they provide you a date that would be the best option.  Then depending on the client timezone you can render the date according to the client's local timezone.

Comment: This ended up throwing an exception for me.  Using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(date, "Central Standard Time") did the trick

Answer (score 1):

**Try like this.**

```
DateTime clientDateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime centralDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(clientDateTime, "Central Standard Time");
```

**Time Zone Id**

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Current Times:");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Los Angeles: {0}", 
                  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Pacific Standard Time"));
Console.WriteLine("Chicago: {0}", 
                  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Central Standard Time"));
Console.WriteLine("New York: {0}", 
                  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Eastern Standard Time"));
Console.WriteLine("London: {0}", 
                  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "GMT Standard Time"));
Console.WriteLine("Moscow: {0}", 
                  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Russian Standard Time"));
Console.WriteLine("New Delhi: {0}", 
                  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "India Standard Time"));
Console.WriteLine("Beijing: {0}", 
                  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "China Standard Time"));
Console.WriteLine("Tokyo: {0}", 
                  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(currentTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Tokyo Standard Time"));
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimebysystemtimezoneid?view=netcore-3.1

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-convert-a-datetime-object-into-specific-timezone-in-c-sharp